# How to find the derivative of $|x^2-1|$?

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

Out teacher never went over finding the derivative of absolute value functions, and I'm not sure how I will go about doing it. Should I make into a piece-wise function?

EDIT: We haven't done chain rule or power rule etc. We only know the definition of a limit $f(x+h)-f(x)\over h$

Comment: Yes, it can be differentiated piecewise, but there are some points where it is not differentiable (do you see where?)

Comment: If $x^2 > 1$ or $|x| > 1$ the derivative is the derivative of $x^2 - 1 = 2x$.  If $x^2 < 1$ or $-1 < x < 1$ the derivative is the derivative of $1 -x^2 = -2x$  At $x = \pm 1$ the function is differentiable only if $-2x = 2x$ which it isn't.

Comment: Oops.  I meant the "the derivative of $x^2-1$"$=2x $.  The equal refers to *words* "the derivative of" and not the $x^2-1$.  But I can see why such "misplaced modifiers" are verboten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** On the intervals $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, the function $|x^2-1|=x^2-1$. On the interval $(-1,1)$, the function $|x^2-1|=-(x^2-1)=1-x^2$. So you'll literally have different derivatives depending on the interval you're looking at.

Notice that the point $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ isn't included. Can you tell why?